# S3 Policy Issue when uploading via Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto, boto3

I m using AWS Lambda to upload a file to S3 and using the command

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file("/tmp/" + fileName, [BUCKET NAME], fileName)
```

And also Lambda policy is defined as

```
{
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKET NAME]",
        "Effect": "Allow"
},
```

But when i run the function it is giving error

```
(<class 'boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError'>, 
S3UploadFailedError('Failed to upload /tmp/[FILE NAME] to [BUCKET 
NAME]/[FILE NAME]: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the 
PutObject operation: Access Denied',), <traceback object at 
0x7f61e9d2ec48>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow `ListBucket` policy as well in order to programmatically put object into s3.

So, your policy would be :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you are missing

> "/*"

in the resource of the policy. For object level operation, the resource should be

> "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*".

Also please make sure that there is no bucket policy denying the access.

More info:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html#using-with-s3-actions-related-to-objects
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex4

Answer (score 0):

Do you have trust relationship for that role to lambda.amazonaws.com?

Also on your policy, should be like the following,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action":   ["s3:PutObject"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKET NAME]/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I see the missing /* at the end of the  bucket name.

Refered Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html